# Setup Puppet at first place

Tags: puppet

I am trying to understand the best practice of setting up Puppet in the first place, let's say I have 1000 existing servers needs to be managed Puppet.

Do I manually install Puppet agent on each or there is a better way.

Sorry if this question is too generic just want to have some idea.

Comment: This is a ServerFault question. But yes, you have to apply the change of installing the `puppet` agent to each machine in much the same way that you currently apply any change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1000 servers could be a lot for a single master instance. of course it will depend on the master specs, and other factors related to the puppet runs.

There are few questions you need to answer first to determine how are you going to go about it such as

1. Puppet Enterprise or Open Source? What is the current configuration night mare you are trying to solve?
2. What is the current configuration data related to the challenge or
   problem you have?
3. What are the current business roles (e.g. web server, load
   balancer,database, ..etc) related to the problem you have? What
   makes a role in terms of configurations?

I would suggest that you start first small  to learn more about the puppet DSL, and its ECO system (master, agent, puppetdb, console/dashboard). I also recommend you start with the free 10 nodes puppet Enterprise as it will let you focus more on the problem at hand not how to configure the puppet masters, and agents, how  to scale them, ..etc.

One more thing install puppet agent every where if you can in NOOP/disabled mode to get at least facts and run it in a masterless fashion using puppet apply when you need  to. i find NOOP mode more useful as it tells you what needs to be changed, also you can enforce changes using --no-noop

hope that will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: **Yes**, Puppet agent would need to be installed on every node. If you are managing 1000 nodes, I would assume you have your own OS image. In this case, its best to add it to the OS image, and use this image on 1000 nodes.